# Get all members who haven't logged in, in past 30 days

Tags: mysql

An example date in my database column looks like this: `1276356747`

Using this column, I need to write a MySQL query that finds which of my users have not logged in in the past 30 days. I do not know how to do this; can anyone help?

Comment: What does your table look like? What have you tried? What are the errors?

Comment: Don't call me a ho. Also, what's the question?

Comment: convert the number in the column into a date and compare whether the delta between today and that date is >= 30

Comment: I have edited the question in such a way that almost all the comments are irrelevant! I'm so helpful!

Comment: Really? Very strange to close this when after an edit, the question is perfectly clear, perfectly answerable, AND answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM members WHERE logged_in < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-2592000`